# Calling other jsp through form : HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp file that calls another jsp to create a bean:

for example :

```
    <form action="klant.jsp" method="post">
    <!-- retreval of possible message from the currentMessage bean -->
    <h3><jsp:getProperty property="message" name="Message"/></h3>

    <div id="klant-name">Klant name : </div><div id="Klant-field"><input type="text" name="loginName" /></div><br> 
    <div id="klant-pwd">Klant Password : </div><div id="Klant-field"><input type="text" name="pwd" /></div><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</form>
```

works fine and does call the jsp file

But the first (form) call in this jsp, (what is the same as above) does not work and give an HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL error.  The second form at the bottom does work??  In neither of the following jsp's there is an post!

```
<form action="feedbacktypical.jsp" method="post" >

    <P>To add a new FeedbackTypical record to the database, submit the
        following data:</P>

            <!-- retreval of possible message from the currentMessage bean -->
    <h3><jsp:getProperty property="message" name="Message"/></h3>

    <TABLE>
        <TR VALIGN=TOP ALIGN=LEFT>
            <TD><B><I>StartDate: <br> (mm/dd/yyyy)
                </I></B></TD>
            <TD><input id="datepicker" NAME="startdate"></TD>
        </TR>

        <TR VALIGN=TOP ALIGN=LEFT>
            <TD><B><I>EndDate: <br> (mm/dd/yyyy)
                </I></B></TD>
            <TD><INPUT id="datepicker2" NAME="enddate"></TD>
        </TR>

        <TR VALIGN=TOP ALIGN=LEFT>
            <TD><B><I>Typical name : <br>
                </I></B></TD>
            <TD><INPUT type="text" name="name"></TD>
        </TR>

        <TR VALIGN=TOP ALIGN=LEFT>
            <TD><B><I>Visibility</I></B></TD>
            <TD><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" name="visibility" value="Visibility" checked><BR></TD>
        </TR>

    </TABLE>    
    <input type="submit" value="Add"/>      
</form>

<p>

<form method="post" action="welcome_feedbackverantwoordelijke.jsp">
<input type=submit name="command" value="Terug naar feedbackverantwoordelijke menu">
</form>
```

Any suggestion would be more then welcome!

Comment: Please follow a good tutorial on Java Web Development using JSPs and Servlets as shown in [SO Servlets wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestion would be more then welcome!

I suggest that you take a look at the servlet methods that the JSP's above call wehn the respective buttons are clicked.  The most likely cause it that one is coded to support POST requests and the other is not.

Comment: This is an action between two jsp's, not ot an servlet!  The second jsp comes from a servlet but why does the one form work (to "welcome_feedbackverantwoordelijke.jsp") and the other one (to "feedbacktypical.jsp") not?  Both are on the jsp redirected jsp?

Comment: Your comment does not make sense.  What is processing the "http://.../klant.jsp" requests?

Comment: I retrieve some values from a db in a servlet.  these values I send to an jsp file where it is used in a pulldownlist.  Together with other input I then redirect (by means of a form)it to and JSP to create my beans with the information provided by the jsp.  When I press the butto to go from the first jsp to the next is when I get these HTTP error.

Comment: So clearly the 2nd JSP does not expect / accept a POST request.  Find out why.